# Minimize the use of "Many repeated if statement"

Tags: javascript

I got a script using TONS of if statement to do a task... But....

### Most of them repeated like:

```
if (parent.getObject()=='apple') {
  if (datatype('fruit')){
    //do a
    parent.setObjectType('fruit');
  }
  else if (datatype('beverage')){
    //do a
    parent.setObjectType('beverage');
  }
}

else if (parent.getObject()=='banana') {
  if (datatype('fruit')){
    //do a
    parent.setObjectType('fruit');
  }
  else if (datatype('beverage')){
    //do a
    parent.setObjectType('beverage');
  }
}

else if (parent.getObject()=='coconut') {
  if (datatype('fruit')){
    //do a
    parent.setObjectType('fruit');
  }
  else if (datatype('beverage')){
    //do a
    parent.setObjectType('beverage');
  }
}           

else if (parent.getObject()=='Dewberry') {
  if (datatype('fruit')){
    //do a
    parent.setObjectType('fruit');
  }
  else if (datatype('beverage')){
    //do a
    parent.setObjectType('beverage');
  }
}
```

Is it possible for me to minimize the use of those repeated codes?
I don't want to use up all the spaces only with lines of if else statement...

Comment: Going to need actual examples of what "task a" and "task b with value X" are :).

In general though, that looks like something you can refactor into function calls.

Comment: It depends what tasks you are doing in your if-else conditions.

Comment: Could you perhaps edit your post to share a specific example of actual code that you've written that you feel has too many if-else statements? I'm not sure if you're aware of this, but given the way your sample code is currently structured, it's possible to completely eliminate every single if-else statement. I'm sure that's not the case with your actual code, so it'd be more helpful for you if you could provide a better example for us to work with.

Comment: its not clear what you want, looking at your code, last code block that starts with if (a) is enough.

Comment: does task for b varies for value of a ?? means if a is 1 do task1 and task 2 for values of b 1 and 2 respectively and if a is foo then do task3 and task4 for values of b 1 and 2 respectively ??

Comment: edited, this is the very very first part of the code.

Comment: You are always returning true. I assume that sometimes you return false?

Comment: Sorry for the typo, I uploaded the old version of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure whether your actual code is a bit more diverse, but what you have posted can exactly be replicated by

```
if (['apple', 'banana', 'coconut', 'Dewberry'].some(function(fruit) {
    return parent.getObject()==fruit;
}) {
    var type = ['fruit', 'beverage'].find(datatype);
    if (type) {
       //do a
       parent.setObjectType(type);
    }
}
```

(where the `find` function is something like the following

```
Array.prototype.find = function(predicate, context) {
    for (var i=0; i<this.length; i++)
        if (predicate.call(context, this[i], i))
            return this[i];
    return null;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more code maybe you could use something like this:

```
function doTask(a, b) {
    var as_string = a + ";" + b;

    switch (as_string) {
        case "1;1":
            //code when a=1 and b=1
                break;
        case "1;2":
            //code when a=1 and b=2
                break;
    }
}

var a = 1;
var b = 1;

doTask(a, b);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [The switch Statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch), it's more efficient in the case you have many possible values:

```
switch (parent.getObject()) {
        case "apple":
            switch (datatype) {
                case "fruit":
                  //Task //do task a
                  //do task b with value 1
                  break;
                case "beverage":
                  //do task a
                  //do task b with value 2
                  break;
            }

            break;
        case "banana":
            // Task a with ...
            break;
       // And put all your possible values
 }
```

You have just to manage the possible vlaues of `parent.getObject()` and `datatype`.

Answer (score 0):

You may or may not be able to reduce if statements depending on your code.

For example if you're adding odd numbers from 0 to n, you an either loop from 0 to n and use if statements to check if the number is odd.  However if you happen to know Gauss's rule 1/2*n*(n+1), you can compute this value in one line without any looping or conditional statements (by removing the k(k+1); k even numbers).

Comment: No it's not aim to sum things up, nor I do understand the latter part of example.

Comment: The point being, without your actual code, it's impossible to tell if you can reduce the number of if's.  

My explaination was that an O(n) complexity problem written over several lines can can be solved in fewer lines and in O(1) complexity with the right analysis.

Comment: Okay, OP posted case specific code.  It looks like there isn't any code that specific to different getObject() values.  He could directly use if(type = fruit)..., else if(type = beverage).